# Scheduling Celery task from Java: "Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination"

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to schedule Celery task from Java.

I'm sending task to RabbitMQ like this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
connection = factory.newConnection();
channel = connection.createChannel();

boolean durable = true;
channel.queueDeclarePassive("celery");
channel.exchangeDeclarePassive("celery");

String MESSAGE_FORMAT = "{\"id\": \"%s\", " + "\"task\": \"%s\", " + "\"args\": [\"%s\"]}";
message = String.format(MESSAGE_FORMAT, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "celery.tasks.add", "2501");
channel.basicPublish("celery", "celery", null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The messages is sent:

```
| routing_key | exchange | message_count |                                                  payload                                                  | payload_bytes | payload_encoding | properties | redelivered |
+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-------------+
| celery      |          | 0             | {"id": "7421864e-aff3-4f2f-b274-9d5eacfc8941", "task": "celery.tasks.add", "args": ["2501"]} | 105           | string           |            | False
```

But when I start worker:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

I get a message:

```
[2016-03-02 16:23:08,457: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: '{"id": "76e0fc3b-3ae0-4603-9099-3cd6bb15ffa9", "task": "celery.tasks.add", "args": ["2501"]}' (105b)
{content_type:None content_encoding:None
  delivery_info:{'redelivered': False, 'delivery_tag': 2, 'routing_key': 'celery', 'exchange': '', 'consumer_tag': 'None4'} headers={}}
```

So the task is not run, because the format is somewhat wrong.
I followed:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html

The task is declared in `tasks.py` like this:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')


@app.task
def add(materialId):
    f = open('logg','w')
    f.write('processing task: ' + materialId)
    f.close()
```

So I'm not sure what should be corrected.
Could you help me on this?

If it's not possible I will fall back to invoking python
process from java but this will complicate the deployment process
so I would like to avoid it.

**Edit:**

To test my method I tried to schedule task this way from python also, but the error is the same:

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='celery', durable=True)
channel.basic_publish(exchange='celery', routing_key='celery', body='{"id": "7421864e-aff3-4f2f-b274-9d5eacfc8941", "task": "celery.tasks.add", "args": ["2501"]}')
```

**Edit2**:

This is not a duplicate of [Interoperating with Django/Celery From Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933833/interoperating-with-django-celery-from-java)
since the answer does not solve my problem: adjusting routing key and exchange did not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interoperating with Django/Celery From Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933833/interoperating-with-django-celery-from-java)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the BasicProperties builder to specify the content type of your message as JSON.

```
channel.basicPublish("celery", "celery", null, 
    new AMQP.BasicProperties().builder().contentType("application/json").build(),
    message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

For how to use it and more examples in Rabbit's documentation:   https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#publishing

For the formats supported by celery for the content type header: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html#serialization

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to get the raw task request that is sent from the python client code and compare that against what you're generating in Java.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about it. It showed me that I should declare exchange as well (I will edit my question). However, I'm still getting the same error, even if I exactly duplicate the message send from python client (I only changed UUID).

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you could try submitting tasks using the [HTTP gateway](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/celery_http_gateway) in the `examples` dir in the celery source - I'm not sure how maintained this particular part of the code is.